# How to cast BitmapDrawable to LayerDrawable in android

Tags: android

This is code snippet.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the main; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications);
    LayerDrawable icon = (LayerDrawable) item.getIcon();




    // Update LayerDrawable's BadgeDrawable
    Utils2.setBadgeCount(this, icon, mNotificationsCount);
    return true;
}
```

It is giving error in line

```
LayerDrawable icon = (LayerDrawable) item.getIcon();
```

BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable

How to cast BitmapDrawable to layer LayerDrawable?

Edit : adding setBadgeCount function.

```
public static void setBadgeCount(Context context, LayerDrawable icon, int count) {

    BadgeDrawable badge;

    // Reuse drawable if possible
    Drawable reuse = icon.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_badge);
    if (reuse != null && reuse instanceof BadgeDrawable) {
        badge = (BadgeDrawable) reuse;
    } else {
        badge = new BadgeDrawable(context);
    }

    badge.setCount(count);
    icon.mutate();
    icon.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_badge, badge);
}
```

Comment: `LayerDrawable` is not a `BitmapDrawable`. You can't cast it to the other.

Comment: @Blackbelt Thanks for response, Then what is best solution for this issue. I have added setBadgeCount() in post.

Comment: what's `BadgeDrawable`? What's the issue?

Comment: @Blackbelt i want to display badge on menu item. I am follwing this link. http://www.jmhend.me/layerdrawable-menuitems  You can find the implementation for BadgeDrawable in this link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only cast the `Drawable` you get from `item.getIcon()` to a `LayerDrawable` if it *actually* is a `LayerDrawable`, i.e. if the `icon` attribute in the menu definition references a drawable defined by a `layer-list`

From the the article you mentionned : the menu definition (`menu/menu_home.xml` in the article, `menu/main.xml` in your case)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_notifications"
        android:title="Notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_notifications"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

The icon (`drawable/ic_menu_notifications`) referenced should be a `layer-list` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
      android:id="@+id/ic_notification"
      android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_email"
      android:gravity="center" />
  <!-- set a place holder Drawable so android:drawable isn't null -->
  <item
      android:id="@+id/ic_badge"
      android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_email" />
</layer-list>
```

Also one of the layer should have `ic_badge` as id. This is the layer used by `setBadgeCount()`

Comment: i have used this code and still error

 MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications);
        LayerDrawable icon = (LayerDrawable) item.getIcon();

        // Update LayerDrawable's BadgeDrawable
        Utils2.setBadgeCount(this, icon, 2);

Comment: error is : java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable